# Datagridview datasource is null after adding values by ui

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagrid

I built a datagridview with columns on the UI,

I added a button which tries to convert the datasource into datatable.

The datagridview binded to bindingsource, which binded to new datatable.

After adding values on the ui and clicking on the button, I try to get the datatable from the datasource but it keeps null.

```
BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
b.DataSource = new DataTable();
grdView.DataSource = b;

public void OnButtonClick()
{
    BindingSource b = (BindingSource)grdView.DataSource;
    DataTable dt = b.DataSource;
    // dt keeps be null (but count is the count of the added rows)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to bind it to a copy of dataSource or to DataSource itself?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The DataSource property can be set to a number of data sources,
>   including types, objects, and lists of types. The resulting data
>   source will be exposed as a list

The data source is a List, not a DataTable. That's probably why it has a count but `dt` ends up null.
The reason to use BindingSource is so that you can access the data withouth going through the UI component (the grid). If you want the data, get it from the BindingSource, don't get it from the grid.